# Constraint layout making dependent view gone the UI is distorted

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have the below UI which is fine till the `Live` image is visible

[image: Correct UI]

Below is the XML layout

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="@dimen/epg_item_container_width"
android:layout_height="@dimen/epg_item_container_with_description_height"
android:layout_margin="1dp"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:padding="10dp">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/program_image"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,16:9"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:src="@drawable/epg_info_default_icon" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/program_image"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/program_image"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/program_image">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/program_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:ems="2"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:gravity="start|top"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:textColor="#d3d3d3"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="2023 Stanley Cup Final" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgLive"
        android:layout_width="42dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/epg_live"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/program_title" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/program_description"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imgLive"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgLive"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgLive"
        tools:text="| US-TV-PG" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/synopsis"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:ems="2"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:textColor="#d3d3d3"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/menu"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imgLive"
        tools:text="Extended game replays from the 2023 Stanley Cup Final." />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/epg_info_default_icon"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now if I change the visibility to `gone` for `imgLive` UI is distorted and `program_description` overlaps with `program_title`

Attached refrence after `gone`

[image]

Comment: both `program_description` and `imgLive` can be hidden? or only one of them?

Comment: @Lino both can be hidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap `imgLive` and `programDescription` inside a simple `LinearLayout`, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/epg_item_container_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/epg_item_container_with_description_height"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/program_image"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,16:9"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:src="@drawable/epg_info_default_icon" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/program_image"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/program_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/program_image">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/program_title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:ems="2"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:gravity="start|top"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:textColor="#d3d3d3"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="2023 Stanley Cup Final" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/group"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/program_title"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/synopsis"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgLive"
                android:layout_width="42dp"
                android:layout_height="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/epg_live"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/program_description"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:text="| US-TV-PG" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/synopsis"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:ems="2"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:textColor="#d3d3d3"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/menu"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/group"
            tools:text="Extended game replays from the 2023 Stanley Cup Final." />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/menu"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/epg_info_default_icon"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```